# The need FOR (the other + verb) -OR- The need OF...?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Is this sentence correct?

> This specific ability to care for others before **the need for the other** to
>   recall that he is living... too.

Context: 
this sentence is used to illustrate the meaning of the "caring for others"'s concept.

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what this is saying with those ellipses, but I'm thinking it *maybe* is? We'd (or at least, I'd) really need more context to be able to provide a useful answer. Speaking more generally, though, yes, it's possible to construct a grammatically correct and fully understandable sentence that says "the need for the other to do something." It's not used super commonly--I don't think, at least--but I wouldn't think twice about hearing it in regular speech.

Comment: Makes little sense to me. Are the ellipses to show that there are parts missing? If so, more context might help.

Comment: I apologies for the ellipses. No they were just suppose to add a little style to the sentence. I removed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ### Caring For Others Concept.
>
> **The [altruistic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/altruistic) ability to care for the well-being of others before
>   *"the others"* ask for or even realise that they need it.**

This is purely an assumption based on the limited meaning I can grasp from your post.